# Перехват GSM пакета

Tags: android, android-sdk

Во время разговора по телефону, голос оцифровывается и передается по каналу GSM. Подскажите, есть возможность перехватить оцифрованный пакет до передачи его в канал GSM?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887636/how-to-record-phone-calls-in-android